# How to convert a JPG or PNG file to RGB_565 format and load to opengles 2.0 in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I am working on a application for android with Opengl es 2.0. Currently I am loading a huge file of size 2048x2048 for texture. I basically have a lot of 256x256 images merged into this one big file to save time loading into the app. I got to know that by converting this jpg file to a RGB_565 i can save some meory and there by loading faster.

I tried to google this but did not find any direct way to convert a jpg to a format that is of RGB_565 to load into opengl. When i try to load the normal jpg to opengl using the extension as RGB_565 i do only get a black screen. Please let me know how to convert a simple jpg file to a format that can be loaded faster for example the RGB_565 format.

Also please let me know your ideas in handling textures with android to make a android application load things faster and give good performance results.

Answer (score 0):

Normal JPEGs are 24-bit. If you want a 565 texture, you'll have to transcode either during the decode or after the decode but before the texture load. If you're bottlenecked on decode, this won't help you; if you're bottlenecked on upload time, expect it to cause no more than a 33% speedup.

If you're currently using a JPEG for the texture, you don't have an alpha channel to worry about. Depending on your quality needs, using an ETC1- (or device-specific compression -- PVRTC is quite nice if you're on a PVR GPU) compressed texture will have a massively larger improvement in both upload time and decode time.

Comment: Internally most JPEGs represent YUV planes.